# Panels to have in Kibana dashboard for troubleshooting applications

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, dashboard, elk

what are some good panels to have in kibana visualisation for developers to troubleshoot issues in applications? I am trying to create a dashboard that developers could use to pinpoint where the app is having issues. So that they could resolve it. These are a few factors that I have considered :

Cpu usage of pod, memory usage of pod, network in and out, application logs are the ones I have got in mind. Any other panels I could add to so that developers could get an idea where to check if something goes wrong in the app.

For example, application slowness could be because of high cpu consumption, app goes down could because OOM kill, request takes longer could be due to latency or cache issues etc Is there any other thing that I could take into consideration if yes please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

So here a few things that we could add are:

1. Number of pods, deployments,daemonsets,statefulsets present in the cluster
2. cpu utilised by the pod(pod wise breakdown)
3. memory utilised by the pod(pod wise breakdown)
4. Network in/out
   5.top memory/cpu consuming pods and nodes
5. Latency
6. persistence disk details
7. error logs as annotations in tsvb
8. Logstreams to check logs within dashboard.